# Custom Record Online Form - Invalid Record Type response

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom record, with a handful of fields, and created an Online Form for this record:

[image]

I have then created the online form from this custom record:

[image]

Finally, when building a html table to post info to NetSuite:

```
<html>
<body>

<form id="myform" action="https://forms.na2.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalcustrecordpage.nl?compid=XXXXXXX&formid=2&h=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" method="post">
<label>Title</label><input name="name" type="text"><br>
<label>Job Number</label><input name="custrecord_str_jobnumber" type="text"><br>
<label>First name</label><input name="custrecord_str_firstname" type="text"><br>
<label>Last name</label><input name="custrecord_str_lastname" type="text"><br>
<label>Company name</label><input name="custrecord_str_companyname" type="text"><br>
<label>Cause of Damage</label><textarea name="custrecord_str_causeofdamage"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

When submitted, I get "Invalid Record Type"

[image]

Could someone point out what I've done wrong??

The Post URL is directly from the Online Form's Publishable Form URL.

Currently I have number of requests increasing, but no submits incrementing.

Comment: Note, all the field types are free-form text, except the Cause Of Damage, which is Text-Area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabled HTML forms - problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem while connecting NetSuite to Shopify. 
Below is my workaround that solved my issue:

```
https://XXXXXXX.extforms.netsuite.com/app/site/crm/externalcustrecordpage.nl?compid=3517976_SB1&formid=34&h=AACffht_oIgqWMk6Mp18gkYHvkbtYcZxkRY&rectype=711
```

In this I just add record type(**&rectype=711**) after that it's working perfectly. And if you having the same issue then you need to add your record type(record type number is given in your record type(also known as internal id)).